# InfluxDB returns bad timestamp. I have no idea why

Tags: c, curl, post, influxdb

I doubt this is a duplicate issue but it might be the same problem as seen elsewhere.

When I try to insert things into InfluxDB via CURL, it just keeps giving me the same invalid timestamp error. I can't really tell why. Below is the data.

```
metaRead=3 metaWrite=0 dspaceOps=0 keyValOps=0 scheduled=1 requests=66 smallReads=0 smallWrites=0 flowReads=0 flowWrites=0 creates=0 removes=0 mkdirs=0 rmdirs=0 getattrs=0 setattrs=0 3862710532
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using the CURL library to send the requests but sending them manually via the command line yields the same response.

Comment: Check and play with time precision setting in your curl url or cli.  Or show examples of your curl and cli insert requests here.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB expects/defaults to nanosecond precision. You're using seconds, by the looks of it. You'll need to modify your `curl` command with the precision query arg:

`curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=weather&precision=s" --data-binary 'temperature,location=1 value=90 1472666050'`